# integrating ajax for option check in product.tpl Open Cart

Tags: php, jquery, templates, opencart

I want to put ajax check script in product.tpl(catalog), it should take the entered text box value and should check in database, if not exists immediately it should give the error message there itself. I have ajax script for that, but not able to integrate as i cannot take textbox name, which is generated from backend.

here is my product.tpl textbox,

```
<?php if ($option['type'] == 'text') { ?>
        <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
          <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
          <span class="required">*</span>
          <?php } ?>
          <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b><br />
          <input type="text" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option['option_value']; ?>" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <?php } ?>
```

and this is my ajax,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()//When the dom is ready 
{
$("#textboxname").change(function() 
{ 

var name = $("#textboxname").val();
if(textboxname.length > 3)
{
$("#availability_status").html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');


$.ajax({  //Make the Ajax Request
    type: "POST",  
    url: "ajax_check.php",  //file name
    data: "name="+ name,  //data
    success: function(server_response){  

   $("#availability_status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request){ 

   if(server_response == '0')//if ajax_check.php return value "0"
   { 
   $("#availability_status").html('<img src="available.png" align="absmiddle"> <font color="Green"> Available </font>  ');
   //add this image to the span with id "availability_status"
   }  
   else  if(server_response == '1')//if it returns "1"
   {  
    $("#availability_status").html('<img src="not_available.png" align="absmiddle"> <font color="red">Not Available </font>');
   }  

   });
   } 

  }); 

}

return false;
});

});
</script>
```

in **textboxname**, what i should put i am not getting. 
plz somebody suggest me

Answer (score 0):

This has to be hardcoded - the option text field has no class nor id attribute. Open up the product detail which has this text field option, open FireBug and inspect that text field input. Find it's `name` attribute value. It may look like this one:

```
<input type="text" value="test" name="option[208]">
```

Now in Your jQuery use this as a selector:

```
$('div.options input[name="option[208]"]').change(function() { ... }
```

This should work.

And one suggestion: instead of using some custom `ajax_check.php` file You should implement Your own action (method) within `/catalog/controller/product/product.php` class and do a POST to URL like `index.php?route=catalog/product/ajax_check` (assuming the new method/action will be called `ajax_check`)...